# Apache commons PredicatedList with no IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, api, collections, apache-commons

Is there a way in [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html) to have a [PredicatedList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/PredicatedList.html) (or similar) which does not throw an IllegalArgumentException if the thing you are trying to add doesn't match the predicate? If it does not match, it would just ignore the request to add the item to the list.

So for example, if I do this:

```
List predicatedList = ListUtils.predicatedList(new ArrayList(), PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
...
predicatedList.add(null); // throws an IllegalArgumentException
```

I'd like to be able to do the above, but with the adding of null being ignored with no exception thrown.

I can't figure out from the JavaDocs if Commons Collections supports this. I'd like to do this if possible without rolling my own code.

Comment: Isn't that the point of a predicated list that you only want things in the list that adhere to the conditions defined for it?  

Why not just use an ordinary list?

Comment: Yes, it is the point of a predicated list. But I want it to quiety ignore things that don't match the predicate, i.e. do the predicate check, but don't complain if it doesn't match.

Comment: That's logically the same behavior as an ordinary list, since you don't care about the predicate check informing you that an element didn't pass.

Comment: No it isn't the same. You can add null to a standard ArrayList as many times as you want. They go in as individual elements. So do "l.add(null); l.add(null); l.size();". l.size() will return 2. I don't want the nulls to be added to the list, hence why I want to use something like a PredicatedList.

Comment: use an ordinary list and do a null check before adding.  It does not make sense to have a predicated list that has a NonNull predicate that contains Null values.  From a different point of view: imagine a database table with a non-null constraint on a column that contains null values: what's the point of constraining it?

Comment: You are totally missing the point I'm trying to make. I do not want the nulls in the list, hence why I looked at PredicatedList. I do not want to have make a null check in all places that use the list. I'd like to pass a reference around to different things that might add to the list. If these places try adding null, I want to ignore that addition. But I do not want to force everywhere to catch the IllegalArgumentException I would get if I used a PredicatedList. So I'd like the functionality of PredicatedList, but without the exception throwing, without having to roll my own!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found [CollectionUtils.filter](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate)). I can probably rework my code to use this, although it would still have been nice to quietly prevent the additions to the list in the first place.

```
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add("A");
    l.add(null);
    l.add("B");
    l.add(null);
    l.add("C");

    System.out.println(l); // Outputs [A, null, B, null, C]

    CollectionUtils.filter(l, PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());

    System.out.println(l); // Outputs [A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just swallow the exception?

```
try
{
    predicatedList.add(null);
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{ 
    //ignore the exception
}
```

You'd probablly need to write a wrapper to do this for you...

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to do it with just library code. But I'm coming to the same conclusion that I'd have to write my own wrapper to swallow the exception.